# How to save a subset of a dataset as .csv file?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-extraction

I would like to save a subset of a dataset as .csv file, but I do not know how to accomplish this. My dataset looks something like this.

| individual | temperature |
| --- | --- |
| bimp25 | 22 |
| bimp25 | 22 |
| bimp25 | 23 |
| Bimp25 | 24 |
| Baur34 | 27 |
| Baur34 | 27 |
| baur34 | 26 |
| Baur34 | 32 |
| bgris2 | 25 |
| bgris2 | 25 |
| bgris2 | 26 |
| bgris2 | 27 |

Say I would like to save the `temperature` of just `bimp25` and `bgris2` into .csv files, how can I accomplish this? Could anyone provide some directions?

Answer (score 0):

First specifiy a directory where the .csv file needs to be saved with `setwd()`. Alternatively, you can select a working directory by executing Ctrl + Shift + H. The latter will also print `setwd("directory_chosen")` in the `console`.

```
individual <- c(rep('bimp25', 3), 'Bimp25', rep('Baur34', 2), 'baur34', 'Baur34', rep('bgris2', 4))
temperature <- c(22, 22, 23, 24, 27, 27, 26, 32, 25, 25, 26, 27)
df <- data.frame(individual, temperature)

my_dir <- 'my_directory'

# save e.g. 'bimp25'
write.csv(subset(df, individual == 'bimp25'), file = file.path(my_dir, 'bimp25.csv'))

# Excel convention for CSV files in some Western European locales
# write.csv2(subset(df, individual == 'bimp25'), file = file.path(my_dir, 'bimp25.csv'))
```

You could also copy the directory (including quotation marks `""`) which appeared in the `console` after you executed Ctrl + Shift + H and chose a directory. Simply replace `my_directory` (in the code above) with this directory.

Answer (score 0):

First, set up the example (thanks @Dion...I'll borrow yours).

```
individual <- c(rep('bimp25', 3), 'Bimp25', rep('Baur34', 2), 'baur34', 'Baur34', rep('bgris2', 4))
temperature <- c(22, 22, 23, 24, 27, 27, 26, 32, 25, 25, 26, 27)
df <- data.frame(individual, temperature)
```

So from here, just index the dataframe and write it to disk. For example, bimp25:

```
write.csv(df[individual="bimp25", ], file = 'out.csv')
```

This says use any row matching the condition `individual="bimp25"` and write that to a CSV.

Or if you want both those conditions in a single file. You can logically combine the two subsets as:

```
a <- df$individual == "bimp25"
b <- df$individual == "bgris2"
```

This gives you two vectors:

```
> a
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> b
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

If you OR the vectors you get TRUE values where you want those rows:

```
> a | b
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Now same as before, index the dataframe and write to disk.

```
write.csv(df[a|b, ], file = 'out.csv')
```